# Countdown text field not updating during countdown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I'm trying to create an inactivity timer for my game and I seem to have everything working except for one part. After a pre-count, I'm instantiating a prefab timer dialog and then in my coroutine I'm trying to update the text field 'timerTextField' located in the that prefab but it isn't updating.

I do have all of the appropriate variables assigned in the editor and my debug.log right after the 'timerTextField.text = s.ToString();' line is counting down correctly. What do I have wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Create Singleton
    public static GameManager gameManagerInstance = null;

    // Set Default Background Color
    public Color defaultColor;

    // Restart variables
    private Vector3 prevMousePosition;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text timerTextField;

    public Object startingScene;
    public GameObject timeOutWarningDialog;  
    public float countdownLength;
    public float countdownDelay;

    private float seconds;
    private Scene currentScene;
    private GameObject gameManager;
    private GameObject canvas;
    private GameObject timerInstance;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (gameManagerInstance == null)
            gameManagerInstance = this;
        else if (gameManagerInstance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        gameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager");
    }

    void Start()
    {       
        prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown || Input.mousePosition != prevMousePosition)
        {
            currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

            if (currentScene.name != startingScene.name)
            {
                StartPreCountTimer();
                if (timeOutWarningDialog != null)
                {
                    timeOutWarningDialog.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
        prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    // GAME TIMER

    public void StartPreCountTimer()
    {
        // Debug.Log("Pre Count Started");
        CancelInvoke();
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Timer") == null)
            Invoke("ShowRestartWarning", countdownDelay);
    }

    void ShowRestartWarning()
    {
        canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");
        timerInstance = Instantiate(timeOutWarningDialog);
        timerInstance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        timerInstance.SetActive(true);

        if (timerInstance.activeSelf == true)
            StartTimer(countdownLength);  
    }

    public void StartTimer(float seconds)
    {
        StartCoroutine("RunTimer", seconds);
    }

    IEnumerator RunTimer(float seconds)
    {
        float s = seconds;
        // Debug.Log("Restart Countdown Started from: " + s);
        while (s > 0)
        {
            if (timerTextField != null)
            {
                timerTextField.text = s.ToString();
                Debug.Log(s);
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            s -= 1;
        }

        if (s == 0)
        {
            RestartGame();
        }
    }

    void RestartGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(startingScene.name);
        // Debug.Log("Game Restarted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? Comment out your other code then try to modify `timerTextField` in  the `Start` function and see if it changes: `void Start(){timerTextField.text = "Hello"}`

Comment: @Programmer, just tried it. I put it right after I instantiate the dialog and it does work (Hello shows up). but it's not updating within IEnumerator with the actual countdown. Why would that be?

Comment: Actually @Programmer, I just tried it a few more times and something is still wrong. When the dialog kicks off it's starts at a random number between 1 and 15 (which by the way, 15 is my countdown time) and stays at that number, unchanged, throughout the countdown.

Comment: 2 questions for you: 1.Did what I said in my first comment work? 2.Is your `Debug.Log(s);` in the `RunTimer` function showing the count-down number correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems comes from the `timerTextField` reference.

It seems like you assign the **Text** component located inside your prefab (which is `timeOutWarningDialog` I think) to the `timerTextField` field inside Inspector.
Because of this, after instantiating a new prefab timer dialog, when you want to change the `timerTextField.text` value, what is changed is the **Text** component inside your prefab and not the one of the instantiated object.

You check this but selecting your object containing the **Text** component inside your prefab (int he Project tab of Unity):

[image: Prefabs Text component value changing]
*(this also explains the weird values you had on start: the previous values reached when you stopped game)*

For your script to work, you simply have to reference the new **Text** component of the instantiated prefab using something like this:

```
void ShowRestartWarning()
{
    timerInstance = Instantiate(timeOutWarningDialog);
    timerInstance.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
    timerInstance.SetActive(true);
    timerTextField = timerInstance.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(); // NEW LINE

    if(timerInstance.activeSelf == true)
        StartTimer(countdownLength);
}
```

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: Glad it helped: working with prefabs can be tricky (especially nested ones) in the first place but once you'll get the hang of it it gets very useful ;)